# Audio plays fine on iPhone and simulator but gets cut off on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avaudioplayer

I'm making an app where the user can press forward/backward buttons. Each time these buttons are pressed, any currently playing audio file stops, and another audio file begins. All of these files do not loop.

I am playing the audio files with code similar to the following:

```
audioURL2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"sound2" ofType:@"aac"]];
            audio2 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL2 error:nil];
            [audio2 play];
            audio1 = nil;
            audio3 = nil;
```

I have ARC enabled, so I'm not explicitly releasing the audio files.

For the most part, the above code works fine. I have not encountered problems on my iPhone device, nor on the iPhone or iPad simulators. Most of the audio on my iPad device also works.

However, one of the audio files does not fully play, even if I avoid touching the buttons while it's playing. Every time I play this audio file on the iPad, I can hear the beginning of the audio file, but then it gets cut off at the same place. This problem only occurs on my iPad, not any of the other devices or simulators.

Here's what I tried so far:

- Deleted the app from the iPad. Cleaned, rebuilt, and re-installed the app
- Restarted the iPad
- Ensured mute / soft mute was off
- Toggled mute / soft mute a few times, and then left mute off
- Increased the iPad's volume

After trying each of the above, I find that the same audio file is cut off at the same place.

Why is this happening, and only to one file in particular? How can I resolve it?

**UPDATE**

I tried using `@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audio2;` in my header, and then tried replacing "strong" with "retain", but I still have the same problem.

Next, I stuck `audio2.numberOfLoops = 1;` before the play call to see what would happen. Interestingly enough, audio2 does repeat, but each loop ends at the cut-off point from before. Maybe something went wrong when sound2 was added to the iPad build?

Comment: is it an older iPad 1? what is the difference in iOS versions between devices and simulators?

Comment: The iPad device is running on 6.0.1, and the iPhone device is on 5.1.1. Both simulators are on 6.1. If it helps, my deployment target is 5.0.

Comment: Odd. are you making sure to retain a reference to the AVAudioPlayer until you are finished with it? (sometimes ARC will clean things up that aren't STRONG linked/references)

Comment: How do I ensure I'm retaining the reference? I'm unfamiliar with ARC.

Comment: Store it to a (member) variable of the class, and nil the reference once playback is complete (or if the view disappears)

Comment: Currently, audioURL2 and audio2 are global variables of types NSURL* and AVAudioPlayer*, respectively. They are initialized just before they are played. They are set to nil if the view unloads or disappears. Should I keep it like this?

Comment: Try using id<AVAudioPlayerDelegate> delegate to respond and check when it thinks it has stopped playing. Other than this it may be something to do with the format, have you tried wav?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that my sound2.aac file got corrupted somehow. I deleted the file from my app and cleaned the project. Then I re-saved the .aac file, brought this new .aac file into the project, and cleaned it again. After running it on my iPad again, sound2.aac played in full.